# How to make sure that values written in a textfield are the same using a simple loop function?

Tags: java, loops, jtextfield

I wrote a simple code just to check the values between textfields and compared whether they are the same or not. I want them to be the same, if not it will produce an error. It's about rewriting an email.

```
    String a = studentemail.getText();
    String b = rewritestudentemail.getText();

    if(a != b){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Student Email rewritten incorrectly.","Error!",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

    }
```

The program persists that there is an error even though I indicated the same string values in both of the fields. Why's that?

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`, so `!a.equals(b)` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your conditional to be this:

```
if(!a.equals(b))
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Student Email rewritten
   incorrectly.","Error!",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
}
```

Make sure you have the `!` before `a.equals(b))` since you only want the error to appear when they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (!a.equals(b)) {
   ...
```

Comment: The "!" worked like wonder. Thank you eKek0!! :D

Answer (score 0):

rather layout your logic like this:

```
if (!a.equals(b)){
 //JoptionPane...
 }
```

In java two strings are compared by using the ".equals()" function.